# Map locations from ASA to powerbi

Tags: powerbi, azure-stream-analytics

I have a Stream Analytics job that generates locations latitude and longitude to powerbi. I am trying to create a map on powerbi.com from these locations. I am creating a map diagram and adding latitude and longitude fields to maps latitude and longitude fields. But nothing is generated. It is expecting some Location field as well. What data should I provide there?

Comment: Hi, did your problem get fixed? Are you still having this issue?

Comment: It is solved now. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need something in the Location field (but it can be a timestamp or an ID or anything). That's what decides how many bubbles you have. Then for each bubble it does an average latitude and longitude to determine where to put the bubble.

Comment: What you mean by how many bubbles? It should show as many bubbles as I have rows in my table.

Comment: Let's say you have 100 rows in your table. If you put a City column in the Location field which has 10 distinct values then you will have 10 bubbles. If you want 100 bubbles then you must have some column with 100 distinct values.

Answer (score 0):

The location field is to specify a "City" location rather then specifying it giving coordinates. If you provide "London" for instance it will create the shapes at the center of London as defined in the maps provider.

On the Long and Lat side, they have to be in a specific format for PBi to recognize them as map fields.

Take a look at the links below for further info on how to change the data type using the editor.

http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-to-map-latitude-longitude/td-p/2479
http://www.radacad.com/how-to-do-power-bi-mapping-with-latitude-and-longitude-only

Hope this helps.